# Angularjs html5Mode(true) page reload error with Node.js Server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have used routeProvider and stateProvider in Angular js with HTML5 mode true.
Everything is working fine until I refresh the page.

I am using Node.js server, I am not getting what to write on server side so that I don't get "Can not find" error.

Please help me with this, I am not getting any answers from other similar posts.

here's the code of state provider

```
   $stateProvider
  .state("/", angularAMD.route({
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'Default/default.html'
  }))
  .state("aboutUs", angularAMD.route({
    url: '/aboutUs',
    templateUrl: 'AboutUs.html'
  }))
  .state("contactUs", angularAMD.route({
    url: '/contactUs',
    templateUrl: 'ContactUs.html'
  }))
  .state("order", angularAMD.route({
    url: '/order',
    templateUrl: 'order/order.html',
    controllerUrl: "order/OrderController"
  }))
  .state("signin", angularAMD.route({
    url: '/signin',
    templateUrl: 'LoginSignup/Login.html',
    controllerUrl: "LoginSignup/LoginController"
  }))
  .state("dashboard", angularAMD.route({
    url: '/dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'Dashboard/dashboard.html',
    controllerUrl: "Dashboard/dashboardController"
  }))
  .state("thankYou", angularAMD.route({
    url: '/ThankYou.html',
    templateUrl: 'ThankYou.html'
  }));
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean. Are you saying the issue is that your content loads only when on the index page and then when changing routes and refreshing it no longer works ?

Comment: for example I have menu link "/order" when I click on it, address in browser becomes localhost:8080/order and I get the order template perfectly but when I refresh the page it says "can not find /order"

Comment: yeah the reason for this is because on refresh your server doesnt have any logic set up to handle the "/order" route, but your client side JS files do, but those are loaded only on the index page. What you need to do is redirect all routes to your index route like Joe Lloyd's answers says to do

Comment: I tried this but this thing is messing with my other routes.
Eg. I am requesting a data using $http.get("/abcd") and in response of this my server sends some data but when I write this code 
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
  res.sendFile('public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
I got index.html text in response.

also this code send me to the home page instead of localhost:8080/order to localhost:8080

Comment: app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
  res.sendFile('public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

using this takes me to the home page instead  of "/order"

Comment: What is the "root" path/file of your angular app, relative to the project ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't got you.
I didn't get the meaning of root of angular app ? 
Are you talking about root which defined on server side ?

Comment: I just found out that this thing is only happening with /order, every other route/link is working. 
Whenever I hit refresh, link gets converted to "localhost:8080/order/"(a forward slash gets attached in the end and due to this its going to home page) and every other link stays same on refresh 
for example "localhost:8080/signin" is working perfectly on refresh and link is also not changing to "localhost:8080/signin/" i.e no forward slash gets attached in the end of the link.
I have checked everything but I am not getting what is the problem ?

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: I have added the code in the post
Let me know what other code do you need. 
Thanks for the help
I appreciate it

Comment: It's very very strange, I changed the name of order state and url to something else and Now it's working.
I have checked but I don't know how's this working

Answer (score 4):

## Use the following snippet in Express

I fixed my app with this in Express.js on the nodejs server.

```
// ### CATCH REFRESH TO INDEX ###
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
  res.sendFile('public/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

it looks in the correct place for the page refresh.

Comment: I did the same thing, with this it goes to my home page not on the current page.

Comment: @NishankSingla I took this from an old project that i was working on I can't quite remember how I figured it out but feel free to checkout my public git repo app.js file [here](https://github.com/joeLloyd/GettingMEAN/blob/master/app.js)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to load your index file with your angular code on refresh, like Joe Lloyd said. In order to allow your other routes to work (the routes that return data) you can check for them and call the next function if it is a match. Here is an example:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {

    // if the requested route matches a route that should return data then
    // we check for it here and call the next function and return, which will skip over serving the index.html page
    if(req.url.indexOf('/get-data-route')){
        return next();
    }

    // if the route does not match an API route serve the index file
    // this is using a template string, if you are using an older version of node
    // replace the template string with a regular string
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`);
});
```

Comment: sending index.html from node server takes me to the home page instead of the page on which I pressed the refresh button. For example if I refresh the page "localhost:8080/order" and this code takes me to the "localhost:8080" instead of "localhost:8080/order"

Comment: Have you tried this? Refreshing while using this code will keep you on "/order" but it will serve this index.html file (hopefully the index file has your angular code) then the angular code should load and render the correct data for "/order". But you are saying this is not the case

Comment: yes I have tried this.
/order is not loading, It is going back to home page localhost:8080