# Refreshing page shows file not found error how to resolve using [angular js + NodeJS/ExpressJS ]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

**Note:** I tried all questions & answer related this topic. Like This and I tried related questions and try to solve it but not success.

I am building angularJS web-app. It's purely based on **AngularJS/HTML**5 and **NodeJS/ExpressJS** and Database side use **mongo DB** then this problem occurs.

***I want To*** `'#'` remove in url and I refresh page then display my current page .But right now display "Not Found 404".I use like this `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and `<base href="/" />` but I am not success.

> I know remove **#** in URL  solution is `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`and
>   `<base href="/" />` But i use **NodeJS/ExpressJS** then I can't use.

***My Url***

```
http://localhost:3000/Tutorial/Routing/StateProvider/index.html#/Setting/StudenList
```

***I want to URL***

```
http://localhost:3000/Tutorial/Routing/StateProvider/index.html/Setting/StudenList
```

**Notes:**

Without this Solution `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`and
 `<base href="/" />` But i use **NodeJS/ExpressJS** Then I want to remove # and refreshing page issue solve

**Code**

*`Folder Structure directive`* .my code very long then i mange snippet (**inside html & js** ). **Not run snippet because i insert all my code just for understand what is mistake my code.**

```
sample2(refreshissue) [Project Name]
-- Public
    -- Tutorial
        --Directive
            -index.html
        --Routing
           --StateProvider
                -Account.html
                -index.html
                -Setting.html
                -StudentListing.html
                -studentDetails.html
                -StateProviderController.js
        --Validation
          -index.html
 -index.html
```

```js
--  StateProviderController.js
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var myapp= angular.module('myapp2',["ui.router"]);
myapp.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider,$urlMatcherFactoryProvider){
    $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
    $stateProvider
.state('TutorialHome', {
            url:'/index',
            templateUrl:'/index.html'
        })
        .state('Profile',{
            url:'/Profile',
            templateUrl:'Profile.html'
        })
        .state('Account',{
            url:'/Account',
            templateUrl:'Account.html'
        })
        .state('Setting',{
            url:'/Setting',
            templateUrl:'Setting.html'
        })
        .state('Setting.StudenListing', {
            url:'/StudenList',
            views: {
                'StudenListing': {
                    templateUrl: 'StudenListing.html',
                    controller:'StudentListingData'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('Setting.StudenListing.StudentList',{
            url:'/StudenList/:StudentID',
            /* templateUrl: 'StudentDetails.html',
            controller:'StudentDetails'*/
            views:{
               'StudentDetails': {
                   templateUrl: 'StudentDetails.html',
                   controller:'StudentDetails'
              }
            }
        })
    ;

   // $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');
 //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});
myapp.controller('StateProviderCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.message ="Welcome To State Provider Page";
    $scope.Home = function()
    {
        window.open('/',"_self");
    }
});

myapp.controller('StudentListingData',function($scope,$http){
    console.log('test');
$http.get('/StudenRecordData').success(function(response){
   // console.log(response);
    $scope.StudentRecorddata =response;
})
});

myapp.controller('StudentDetails',function($scope,$http,$stateParams){
    $scope.StudentID = $stateParams.StudentID;
    //console.log( $scope.StudentID);

    $http.get('/StuentRecordSearch/'+ $stateParams.StudentID).success(function(response){
        //console.log(response);
        $scope.StuentDetails =response[0];
    })

});
==================================================================================================================================================================
----  app.js
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var url =require('url');

var index = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
/*var basepathArray = ['/Tutorial/Routing/StateProvider/','/Tutorial/Validation/','/Tutorial/Directive/'];
app.get('/!*',function(req,res){
  var basePath ="";
  for(var i=0;i<=basepathArray.length-1;i++)
  {
    if(req.originalUrl.search(basepathArray[i]) != -1){
      basePath =basepathArray[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  if(basePath!="")
  {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('public'+basePath+'index.html'));
  }
  else {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/index.html'));
  }



});*/

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});



module.exports = app;
```

```html
=================================================================================
 --  Account.html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<h1>Account  page</h1>

=================================================================================
--  index.html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp2">
<title>Index | Angular Js</title>
<base href="/Tutorial/Routing/StateProvider/" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="StateProviderController.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="StateProviderCtrl">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="TutorialHome"> State Routing</a>
        </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a ui-sref="Profile">Profile</a></li><!--State Transition on click-->
                <li><a ui-sref="Account">Account</a></li><!--State Transition on click-->
                <li><a ui-sref="Setting">Setting</a></li><!--State Transition on click-->
                <li style="float: right;" ><a ng-click="Home()"> Home</a></li><!--State Transition on click-->
            </ul>

    </div>
</nav>


<div class="container" ng-controller="StateProviderCtrl">
    <!-- we use ui-view instead of ng-view -->
    <!--{{message}}<br>-->
    <ui-view></ui-view>

</div>


</body>
</html>
=================================================================================
--  Profile.html
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<h1>Profile  page</h1>

=================================================================================
--  Setting.html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<div>
    <h1>Setting page</h1>
    <strong>This page shows Nested states & views. Click on below links to see Nested states in action.</strong><br>
    <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref="Setting.StudenListing">Show Listing</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:beige;display: inline-block">
                <div ui-view="StudenListing"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
  <!--  <div ui-view="Descriptions"></div><br>
    <div ui-view="Price"></div>-->
=================================================================================
--  StudentListing.html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <!--<ui-view></ui-view>-->


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:beige;">

            <h2>Student Listing</h2>
            <p>All Talented Student List</p>
            <table class="table" >
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Eduction</th>
                    <th>Email ID</th>
                    <th>Details <!--<div ui-view="StudentDetails"></div>--></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in StudentRecorddata">
                    <td>{{data.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.Eduction}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.Email}} </td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ui-sref="Setting.StudenListing.StudentList({StudentID:$index})">View Details</button> </td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:beige;">
           <!-- <div ui-view="StudenListing"></div>-->
            <div ui-view="StudentDetails"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
=================================================================================
-- studentDetails.html
------------------------------------------------------------------------------<div>
    <h2>Student Details </h2>
    <br>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Stuent Id:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="form-control-static">{{StudentID}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="form-control-static">{{StuentDetails.Name}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Age:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="form-control-static">{{StuentDetails.Age}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Eduction:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="form-control-static">{{StuentDetails.Eduction}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="form-control-static">{{StuentDetails.Email}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">MobileNumber:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="form-control-static">{{StuentDetails.MobileNumber}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Gender:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <p class="form-control-static">{{StuentDetails.Gender}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please say how you have routed the service in angular, node.js request url in the routes in order to troubleshoot this problem

Comment: Thank For Answer. I tried your code .but this code redirect in single page . like example is i still work in page http://localhost:3000/Tutorial/Routing/StateProvider/Setting‌​/StudenList/StudenLi‌​st/1 now i refresh page then redirect public/index.html page http://localhost:3000/.

Answer (score 10):

> This is because the web server receiving the request looks for a resource matching the full url on the server, which doesn't exist because the angular portion of the url refers to a route in your angular application and needs to be handled in the client browser

### The way to fix this is by rewriting all virtual urls to the main angular index.html file

> AngularJS + NodeJS/ExpressJS - Routes to prevent 404 error after page refresh in html5mode

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

// serve angular front end files from root path
router.use('/', express.static('app', { redirect: false }));

// rewrite virtual urls to angular app to enable refreshing of internal pages
router.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('app/index.html'));
});

module.exports = router;
```

> AngularJS + IIS - URL Rewrite Rule to prevent 404 error after page refresh in html5mode (for apache [click here](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/))

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

[Referred from](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/07/26/angularjs-enable-html5-mode-page-refresh-without-404-errors-in-nodejs-and-iis)

additional way to fix this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34817349/2218635

Comment: but he says he is using Apache as the static file/web server

Comment: thanks for answer . your solution i already triad.but not success.this solution redirect to single page .but i want to refresh any page then display current page

Comment: please get the current url and send it

Comment: i try also but i want to get link like 'http://localhost:3000/Tutorial/Routing/StateProvider/Setting/StudenList/StudenList/0' after refresh then 404 File Not Found . but i add # in url like this  'http://localhost:3000/Tutorial/Routing/StateProvider/#/Setting/StudenList/StudenList/0' then work completely. but i want to remove # in url and refresh my page

Comment: one question i create a .htaccess file but i this file move Public Directory. so htacces file are location is right or wrong ?? if wrong so plz tell me which location put htacces file in node js server

Comment: not need, see `res.sendFile(path.resolve('app/index.html'));` this line send for a single page. now you need to get prev url and assign like as dynamic url . does make sense?

Answer (score 5):

This is what I have for my app.

From the [API docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider#html5Mode) for HTML5 mode

> if (HTML5 mode is) enabled and requireBase are true, and a base
>   tag is not present, an error will be thrown when $location is
>   injected.

So, you need the `base` tag. I've tried without the base tag and `requireBase` to be false but it still seems to throw an error for me.

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

**app.route.js[Angular.js]**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    // This removes '#' and makes URL pretty
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: true
    });

    // Default path if nothing is matched. State would become 'landing'
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('landing', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: "/dashboard/landing/templates/index.html",
            controller: 'LandingController'
        }).state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: "/dashboard/about/templates/index.html",
            controller: 'AboutController'
        });

});
```

Once you redirect yourself from `'landing'` to `'about'` state and the route changes to `/about`, the URL is only changed on the browser and the server does not know of this. So, when you refresh, the server does not know what `/about` path means. Thus, you need to redirect `/about` path (or any path that belongs to angular's routes) to `index.html` and then angular redirects you back to `/about` automagically.

**app.js[Express.js]**

```
//  dashboard route should deliver templates instead of loading angular JS app so this should come before the next one
app.use('/dashboard', express.static(__dirname + '/public/dashboard'));

// put all the API methods here and separate from the redirection to `index.html`
app.use('/api', routes.apiRoutes); 

// all the paths that do not start with `/dashboard` or `/api` is/should be angular route and thus, redirect back to `index.html`
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

*Side note*

On another app, I've seen an issue where refreshing the browser appends a trailing slash at the end of the path (`/`) and after the redirection, Angular app could not recognize the path from the url `/about` vs `/about/` so it redirected me back to the landing page.

I resolved this by adding this in **app.route.js**

```
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks For answer i tried your code but this code redirect in single page . like example is i still work in page `http://localhost:3000/Tutorial/Routing/StateProvider/Setting/StudenList/StudenList/1` now i refresh page then redirect public/index.html page  `http://localhost:3000/`.

Comment: i want to any page refresh then still page on web not redirecting any single  page ...Thanks

Comment: Add console.log(req.originalUrl); in your express. What does it say when you refresh the page?

Comment: 1 up vote for Your Code working  in redirect single page . my problem still there ...

Comment: @Sumitpatel You should update the code so I can see what is incorrect.

Comment: hello @tusz i update my questions and insert to code .check it

Comment: `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index'); $locationProvider.html5Mode({ requireBase: true, enabled: true }); ` needs to be there. they are commented out @Sumitpatel

Comment: also  what's in this routes file? `var index = require('./routes/index');`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in application-configuration.js file as follows:

please find this portion: "indexController"

```
var indexController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, blockUI) {
            var baseUrl="/Tutorial"; //here it will be your site name
}
```

just add this baseUrl in your url link.

Answer (score 0):

Well... this issue is something everyone might have encountered when starting with node.js along with angular.

**First Issue is the '#' in url and like everyone suggested just do this**

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Now the refresh issue will happen, expected... again.

**Why it happens?**

The request is sent to node.js server and there is nothing in place there to prevent it.

### How to solve it?

Just make sure the corresponding trailing requests are mapped to the main angular view. If you have only one `ng-app` for whole program then just redirect to main view.

Add something like this on your node.js server

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Here `index.html` is my main view which is linked to the main controller file where code for routing exists. If I am trying to load `/about` it'll go to the controller and then the controller will load the specific view.

This is very easy way to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for answer . i try you code . remove `#` in url is ok. but now i refresh page then error like that `ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'c:\Users\Sumit\IdeaProjects\sample2(refreshissue)\index.html'`..

Comment: What is the name of your main view. the index.html that I have marked there is supposed to be the main file via which other views are regulated. Please make sure that you point your main file to it. Everything else will work properly. Update me on this. Following.

Comment: ya i tried .but same error . i define my folder directive . my main folder `public` and inside a `index.html` page . folder structure update in my question. not solve refresh issue .

Comment: there are 4-5 index.html in the directory structure listed above. Which one is your main index.html,  via which other views are loaded? Just reference it to that. @Sumitpatel

Comment: i hop you are not understand my question ...? because i using more than 2 state provider in different different `Directive folder` and `routing folder` `index.html` .  and i refresh any page then not redirect `main index.html ` i redirect to current page . but right now i refresh link `http://localhost:3000/Tutorial/Routing/StateProvider/index.html#/Setting/StudenList` then `page not fund error are there`

Comment: the two state provider will have two different links right? As in different ng-app all together. Let's say I have an app where for example.com/* I use one ng-app and for example.com/dashboard/* I have another ng-app, in that case I will redirect dashboard/* traffic to it and normal example.com/* to another one.